# distanceFromLocation - getting error

Tags: iphone, core-location

I have the following code in place:

NewWorkoutViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "StatisticsViewController.h"
#import "MyCLController.h"
#import "Workout.h"
#import "Route.h"

@interface NewWorkoutViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> {
    MyCLController *locationController;

    IBOutlet UIButton *saveButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *backButton;

    IBOutlet UIButton *startButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *stopButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *resetButton;

    IBOutlet MapViewController *mapViewController;
    IBOutlet StatisticsViewController *statisticsViewController;

    IBOutlet UIView *routePickerView;
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *routePicker;

    IBOutlet UIView *activityPickerView;
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *activityPicker;

    IBOutlet UIView *intensityPickerView;
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *intensityPicker;

    IBOutlet UILabel *time;
    IBOutlet UITextField *route;
    IBOutlet UITextField *activity;
    IBOutlet UITextField *intensity;
    IBOutlet UILabel *speed;
    IBOutlet UILabel *distance;
    IBOutlet UILabel *averageSpeed;
    IBOutlet UILabel *calories;

    NSMutableArray *routeArray;
    NSMutableArray *activityArray;
    NSMutableArray *intensityArray;

    NSMutableArray *newWorkoutArray;

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;   

    int counterInt;
    NSTimer *myTimer;
    NSInteger *startInterval;
    NSInteger *stopInterval;
    NSInteger *elapsedInterval;

    NSString *mapID;
    int pickerChoice;

    NSString *walkID;
    NSString *activityValue;
    NSString *intensityValue;

    CLLocation *currentlocation;
    CLLocation *previouslocation;

    //double kilometers;
    //double totalkilometers;
}

@property (retain,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *newWorkoutArray;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSTimer *myTimer;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

-(IBAction)backButton;
-(IBAction)saveButton;
-(IBAction)mapButton;
-(IBAction)statisticsButton;
-(IBAction)startTimerButton;
-(IBAction)stopTimerButton;
-(IBAction)resetButton;

-(IBAction)routePickerShow;
-(IBAction)activityPickerShow;
-(IBAction)intensityPickerShow;

-(IBAction)routeDoneButton;
-(IBAction)activityDoneButton;
-(IBAction)intensityDoneButton;

-(void)showActivity;
-(void)didCreateWorkout:(NSString *)thisTime
                  Route:(NSString *)thisRoute
               Activity:(NSString *)thisActivity
              Intensity:(NSString *)thisIntensity   
                  Speed:(NSString *)thisSpeed
               Distance:(NSString *)thisDistance
           AverageSpeed:(NSString *)thisAverageSpeed
               Calories:(NSString *)thisCalories;

-(void)initialiseWorkoutViewController;
-(void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location;


@end
```

NewWorkoutViewController.m

```
-(void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location 
{   
    currentlocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:+37.364305 longitude:-122.027901];
    previouslocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:+37.364429 longitude:-122.028048]; //70301

    if(previouslocation != nil) {           
        CLLocationDistance kilometers = [currentlocation distanceFromLocation:previouslocation]; // Error occurring here

        NSLog(@"Distance Meters: %f", kilometers);

        [speed setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[location speed]]];
        [distance setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", kilometers / 1000]];

        previouslocation = currentlocation;
    }
}
```

MyCLLocation.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


@protocol MyCLControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location;
- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error;
@end

@interface MyCLController : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    id delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

MyCLLocation.m

```
#import "MyCLController.h"


@implementation MyCLController

@synthesize locationManager;
@synthesize delegate;

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self; // send loc updates to myself
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [self.delegate locationUpdate:newLocation];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    [self.delegate locationError:error];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [self.locationManager release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I get the following error message on the CLLocationDistance line in NewWorkoutViewController.m "Incompatible types in initialization".

Anyone any thoughts ?

Regards,
Stephen

Comment: I know that this doesn't help your question but it's very misleading calling that variable kilometres - the distanceFromLocation method returns metres ;)

Comment: Thanks Dean, believe it or not I actually had the following line of code originally:

CLLocationDistance kilometers += [currentlocation distanceFromLocation:previouslocation]/1000;

hence the reason for kilometers instead of meters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 3130
            CLLocationDistance kilometers = [currentLocation getDistanceFrom:previousLocation] / 1000;
        #else
            CLLocationDistance kilometers = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:previousLocation] / 1000;         
        #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it in XCode but don't get the error that you get :(

I tried :

```
-(void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location 
{   
    CLLocation *currentlocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:+37.364305 longitude:-122.027901];
    CLLocation *previouslocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:+37.364429 longitude:-122.028048]; //70301

    if(previouslocation != nil) {           
        CLLocationDistance kilometers = [currentlocation distanceFromLocation:previouslocation]; // Error occurring here

        NSLog(@"Distance Meters: %f", kilometers);

        [speed setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[location speed]]];
        [distance setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", kilometers / 1000]];

        previouslocation = currentlocation;
    }
}
```

Can you edit your question and show where you have defined currentlocation and previouslocation - I've defined them in the method just to test it but I assume you've defined them somewhere else in your class (probably the .h file)?

Comment: I've included the .h as requested.

Comment: Dean, the apple documentation refers to the the following line of code: -(CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location, 
when using distanceFromLocation. I feel a bit stupid asking this but do I need it, I'm guessing I do ?

Comment: Hmm, you .h file looks exactly as I expected - CLLocation * for both currentlocation and previouslocation. I assume you also have the line _#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>_ at the top of the .h file?

Comment: In that case I have no idea why you would get a compiler error there - it makes no sense - the method returns a CLLocationDistance and that's what you've declared kilometres as. And I don't get the error when I compile the code on my machine. The only other suggestion I have is to do a clean and rebuild from scratch (Build -> Clean all Targets)

Comment: Thanks for your help Dean, I'll keep at it.

Comment: Folks, I'm still struggling with this, all help appreciated.